# plotly mapbox: how to change map language?

Tags: plotly, mapbox

how to change the language in map to the local language, just like google map. e.g. if it is in japan, show japanese, if it is in china, show chinese.

full code:

```
import plotly.graph_objects as go
import plotly.io as pio
import plotly
import pandas as pd

lon1 = [113.076843, 113.154191, 113.737213, 113.842405, 114.244183 ]
lat1 = [23.10993, 23.218533, 23.047626, 22.987975, 22.601581 ]
node1 = ["1","2","3","4","5"]

lon2 = [113.364738, 113.664108, 113.661705,114.244183]
lat2 = [22.997112, 22.878038, 22.869216, 22.601581]
node2 = ["6",'7','8','5']


mapbox_access_token = 'your token'

df = pd.DataFrame({'name': node1,
                   'latitude': lat1,
                   'longitude': lon1})

df2 = pd.DataFrame({'name': node2,
                   'latitude': lat2,
                   'longitude': lon2})


lon_trip1 = lon1
lat_trip1 = lat1

lon_trip2 = lon2
lat_trip2 = lat2


fig = go.Figure()
fig.add_trace(go.Scattermapbox(
    lat=list(df['latitude']),
    lon=list(df['longitude']),
    mode="markers+lines+text",
    name="trip1",
    marker=dict(size=10),
    textposition='middle center',
    textfont=dict(size=7, color='white'),
    text=[df['name'][i] for i in range(df.shape[0])]
))


fig.add_trace(
    go.Scattermapbox(
        lat=list(df2['latitude']),
        lon=list(df2['longitude']),
        mode="markers+lines+text",
        name="trip2",
        marker=dict(size=10),
        textposition='middle center',
        textfont=dict(size=7, color='white'),
        text=[df2['name'][i] for i in range(df2.shape[0])]
    ))

# fig.update_layout(
#     margin={'l': 113, 't': 24, 'b': 22, 'r': 115},
#     mapbox=dict(style='carto-positron',
#                 center=go.layout.mapbox.Center(lon=113.664, lat=22.878),
#                 pitch=0,
#                 zoom=8)
# )

fig.update_layout(
dict(margin=dict(l=113, t=24, r=115, b=22),
              mapbox=dict(accesstoken=mapbox_access_token,
                          center=dict(lat=22.878, lon=113.664),
                          style='light',
                          zoom=8))
 )


fig.show(id='the_graph', config= {'displaylogo': False})
```

Answer (score 0):

You can change the language in the admin area where you received the token.

[image]

Comment: I have changed the language in mapbox style component. I could see in the mapbox studio editor the language on the map is changed. However, when I run above code the plotly still produce the map in English as before, nothing changed. what's the problem?

Comment: just figure out that it needs to be published. but I could not find the light style optionb for language switch.  how to change the lanuguage for style='mapbox://styles/mapbox/light-v10'